# How pivot is used to select first three owners of a particular ticketid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
   ticketid owner   owndate
    1001    LEWIS   2004-06-18 14:15:11.000
    1001    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:16:54.000
    1001    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:21:12.000
    1001    NULL    2004-09-01 09:56:11.000
    1001    CALDONE 2005-02-02 08:38:28.000
    1001    SINCLAIR    2005-02-02 08:54:02.000
    1002    NULL    2005-02-02 08:40:06.000
    1002    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:33:47.000
    1002    NULL    2004-08-31 15:12:46.000
    1002    NULL    2004-09-24 10:03:09.000
    1003    RAMSDALE    2004-09-24 10:04:24.000
    1003    MOTIKA  2004-08-31 14:51:45.000
    1003    NULL    2004-08-31 15:05:50.000
1003    MURTHY  2004-09-02 14:50:28.000
1004    NULL    2004-08-31 15:28:37.000
1004    NULL    2004-09-24 09:24:21.000
1005    WILSON  2004-09-02 16:29:43.000
```

Output should be

```
ticketid owner1 owner2  owner3
1001    NULL    NULL    NULL
1002    NULL    NULL    NULL
1003    NULL    NULL    NULL
1004    NULL    NULL    NULL
1005    NULL    NULL    NULL
1006    NULL    NULL    NULL
1007    NULL    NULL    NULL
1008    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**Instead of NULL. It should show the difference in owndate. i.e. Particular Owner is assigned for a ticket for how long. I want to show first three owners of a particular ticket.**  Please guide. 
I calculated the time difference as :

```
WITH rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY owndate) AS rn
        FROM    tkownerhistory
        )
SELECT mc.ticketid, mc.owner,mc.owndate
,left('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 86400*30 AS VARCHAR),2) + ' months ' +
left('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 86400 AS VARCHAR),2) + ' days ' +
left('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
right('0' + CAST(((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
right('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)

 as TimeDiffInHours
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON   mc.rn = mp.rn-1
order by mc.owndate
```

this shows output

```
1001    LEWIS   2004-06-18 14:15:11.000 00 months 00 days 00:01:43
1001    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:16:54.000 00 months 00 days 00:04:18
1001    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:21:12.000 00 months 00 days 00:12:35
1002    WILSON  2004-06-18 14:33:47.000 02 months 07 days 01:13:32
1005    MOTIKA  2004-08-31 14:47:19.000 00 months 00 days 00:04:26
1003    MOTIKA  2004-08-31 14:51:45.000 00 months 00 days 00:14:05
1003    NULL    2004-08-31 15:05:50.000 00 months 00 days 00:06:56
1002    NULL    2004-08-31 15:12:46.000 00 months 00 days 00:15:51
```

**But i am not sure how it can be pivoted and only first three owners of a particular ticket id are selected as columns and data will be "timediffinhours"**

Comment: For particular ticketid you should pass parameter.Secondly first you should get the basic query right,then later you can esily pivot it.like
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [owner] ORDER BY owndate ) AS rn
        FROM    tkownerhistory where ticketid=1001.Is it correct ?

Comment: I cannot partition it by owner as I am using row number to calculate the difference between two owndates of a ticket.

Comment: are you able to get correct first three owner with your query ?

Comment: No. But i am able to get difference in owndates using row number.I am comparing two rows as   mc.rn = mp.rn-1 and calculate difference among them..provide a method to get a solution leaving my query.

Comment: r u using 2012 or above ?

Comment: I want to display owner1, owner2,owner3 in pivoted columns based on top three records of a particular ticket.

Comment: check the latest.i have corrected for 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption 
i) you need to pivot for only 3 owner.

ii) I am showing datediff in second,you can easily convert them in disered format like above.

Also let me know, where is the problem,

```
    Declare @tkownerhistory table(ticketid int, [owner] varchar(50),owndate datetime)
      insert into @tkownerhistory values(1001,'LEWIS','2004-06-18 14:15:11.000'),
        (1001,'WILSON','2004-06-18 14:16:54.000'),
        (1001,'WILSON','2004-06-18 14:21:12.000'),
        (1001,NULL ,'2004-09-01 09:56:11.000'),
        (1001,'CALDONE','2005-02-02 08:38:28.000'),
        (1001,'SINCLAIR','2005-02-02 08:54:02.000'),
        (1002,NULL ,'2005-02-02 08:40:06.000'),
        (1002,'WILSON','2004-06-18 14:33:47.000'),
        (1002,    NULL,'2004-08-31 15:12:46.000'),
        (1002,    NULL,'2004-09-24 10:03:09.000'),
        (1003,'RAMSDALE','2004-09-24 10:04:24.000'),
        (1003,'MOTIKA','2004-08-31 14:51:45.000'),
        (1003,    NULL,'2004-08-31 15:05:50.000'),
    (1003,    'URTHY','2004-09-02 14:50:28.000'),
    (1004 ,   NULL ,   '2004-08-31 15:28:37.000'),
    (1004 ,   NULL,   '2004-09-24 09:24:21.000'),
    (1005,    'WILSON','2004-09-02 16:29:43.000')

    ;With CTE as
(
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ticketid ORDER BY ticketid,owndate ) AS rn
        --,datediff(day,owndate,lead(owndate,1)over(order by owndate))dtdiff
        FROM    @tkownerhistory  

)
,CTE1 as
(
select * 
from cte 
where rn<=4
)
--select * from cte1
select  a.ticketid
        ,datediff(second,a.owndate,b.owndate)[owner1]
            ,datediff(second,b.owndate,c.owndate)[owner2]
    ,datediff(second,c.owndate,d.owndate)[owner3]
from 
cte1 A 
outer apply(select * from cte1 where ticketid=a.ticketid and rn=2)b
outer apply(select * from cte1 where ticketid=a.ticketid and rn=3)c
outer apply(select * from cte1 where ticketid=a.ticketid and rn=4)d
where a.rn=1
```